# How to create Google Scripts loop to activate and copy data from each tab in the workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet that has X number of sheets (the number of sheets will change constantly). The format of the data in each sheet is the same. I want to create a macro to activate each sheet in the Spreadsheet and pull data from specific cells into a new sheet (essentially I'm consolidating info from each sheet in one place). I see how to activate a sheet using `getSheetByName()`, but the name and number of sheets will change regularly. I was hoping to create a loop that does the following:

1. Activate the *first* sheet.
2. Copy data from a few cells in that sheet to a "Dashboard" sheet.
3. Activate the *next* sheet.
4. Copy data from a few cells in that sheet to a "Dashboard" sheet.
5. Repeat until *all* sheets have been reviewed.

I can use the following code to activate the next sheet, but how do I make a loop that stops after the last sheet?

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  var nextSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1;
  if (nextSheetIndex > spreadsheet.getSheets().length) { nextSheetIndex = 1; }
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[nextSheetIndex - 1], true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  nextSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1;
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to activate `Sheet` to perform changes. Since you want to iterate over each `Sheet` in a `Spreadsheet`, use the `getSheets()` method to retrieve an `Array` of `Sheet` instances.

Then, iterate over each `Sheet` with a loop of your liking (`for`,`for...in`,`forEach()`,etc) and, during each iteration of the loop, access the `Range` value you want to pull data from via `getRange(yourRangeReference).getValue()` and copy it to the destination `Sheet`.

If you need to check and account for number of sheets changing dynamically, *while* you are iterating over them, `getNumSheets()` method on each iteration step and, if its result is greater than initial, access and then `push()` this sheet into the `Array`.

**Useful links**

1. [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) on `for` loop (the simplest one);
2. `SpreadsheetApp` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) for Spreadsheet service;
3. Developer guide on [extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets);

Comment: Those are really helpful resources. I think the loop will work just fine. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding! :)